# FSC: error FS2024: Static linking may not use assembly that targets different profile with oxyplot example and FsXaml

Tags: wpf, f#, oxyplot, fsxaml, gjallarhorn

I'm using `oxyplot` with `fsxaml` and `gjallarhorn`. It works when using it directly and binding to output from DataPoint(x,y). However when I try the following example from [SimpleDemoFsharp](https://github.com/objorke/oxyplot/tree/1c8490b4d7ff2e0a0305f6da38de9be577ee5df6/Source/Examples/WPF/SimpleDemoFsharp/):

```
type MainViewModel() =
    let myModel = PlotModel()
    do 
        myModel.Series.Add(FunctionSeries(cos, 0.0, 10.0, 0.1, "cos(x)"))
    member mainWindow.MyModel with get() = myModel
```

The build fails with `FSC: error FS2024: Static linking may not use assembly that targets different profile.` The error appears to be caused by this line: `myModel.Series.Add(FunctionSeries(cos, 0.0, 10.0, 0.1, "cos(x)"))`, if I uncomment it the project compiles. I have tried targetting lower .NET versions, and creating fresh projects but without much success. Is there a workaround? From search it appears that this maybe caused some PCL profile issues.

The example on its own compiles and works (i.e. no other nuget packages installed just oxyplot and oxyplot.wpf).

**EDIT:** After further testing the issue appears to be  coming from a combination of FsXaml and Oxyplot. For example, when trying to load the MainWindow.xaml via FsXaml.

The fsc.exe command from VS2015 is below:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\F#\4.0\Framework\v4.0\fsc.exe
>   -o:obj\x64\Debug\Gjallarhorn160611.exe -g --debug:full --noframework --define:DEBUG --define:TRACE --doc:bin\Debug\Gjallarhorn160611.XML --optimize- --platform:x64 --resource:obj\x64\Debug\Gjallarhorn160611.g.resources -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference
>   Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp.NETFramework\v4.0\4.4.0.0\FSharp.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\FsXaml.Wpf.2.1.0\lib\net45\FsXaml.Wpf.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\FsXaml.Wpf.2.1.0\lib\net45\FsXaml.Wpf.TypeProvider.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\Gjallarhorn.Bindable.0.0.3-beta1\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\Gjallarhorn.Bindable.dll" -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\Gjallarhorn.Bindable.Wpf.0.0.3-beta1\lib\net45\Gjallarhorn.Bindable.Wpf.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\Gjallarhorn.0.0.3-beta1\lib\portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81+wp8+MonoAndroid1+MonoTouch1\Gjallarhorn.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\OxyPlot.Core.1.0.0-unstable2100\lib\net45\OxyPlot.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\OxyPlot.Wpf.1.0.0-unstable2100\lib\net45\OxyPlot.Wpf.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\OxyPlot.Wpf.1.0.0-unstable2100\lib\net45\OxyPlot.Xps.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PresentationCore.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\PresentationFramework.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Core.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Numerics.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Users\username\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\Gjallarhorn160611_A\packages\Expression.Blend.Sdk.1.0.2\lib\net45\System.Windows.Interactivity.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xaml.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\System.Xml.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\UIAutomationTypes.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\WindowsBase.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Collections.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ComponentModel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Globalization.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.IO.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.Expressions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.Parallel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Linq.Queryable.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Net.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Net.Requests.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ObjectModel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Security.Principal.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Xml.XDocument.dll"
>   -r:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\Facades\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll"
>   --target:exe --warn:3 --warnaserror:76 --vserrors --LCID:1033 --utf8output --fullpaths --flaterrors --subsystemversion:6.00 --highentropyva+ --sqmsessionguid:9587e2f2-adad-4417-931b-00c055df82f8 "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Temp.NETFramework,Version=v4.5.AssemblyAttributes.fs"
>   AssemblyInfo.fs Model.fs Context3.fs Program.fs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, PCL and Type Providers don't play nice together. This appears to be caused by [VisualF# Issue 99](https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues/99/). Workaround is to move the ViewModel code to a separate library.

Answer (score 2):

Pretty sure the error is in:

Gjallarhorn.Bindable.dll

and

Gjallarhorn.dll

For some reason you are referencing the portable libs.

Edit the paths to point to the full .net version

Comment: I can reproduce the error just with fsxaml and oxyplot. But i also suspected the portable libraries. Will check your suggestion. Thx.

Comment: I'm referencing dlls under lib/net45 for both FSXaml and OxyPlot. In this case I'm not referencing gjallarhorn.  I tried Oxyplot's PCL but got the same error. Is it possible that FsXaml is PCL?